# How can I put same width in span element wrapped on li elements

Tags: jquery, html, css, alignment, size

my code is :

```css
.qty{
display: inline-block;
min-width: 10px;
padding: 3px 7px;
font-size: 12px;
font-weight: 700;
line-height: 1;
color: #fff;
text-align: center;
white-space: nowrap;
vertical-align: baseline;
border-radius: 10px;
position: relative;
bottom: 20px;
background-color: #137EC4;}
.num {
display: inline-block;
min-width: 10px;
padding: 3px 7px;
font-size: 12px;
font-weight: 700;
line-height: 1;
color: #fff;
text-align: center;
white-space: nowrap;
vertical-align: baseline;
border-radius: 10px;
position: relative;
bottom: 3px;
background-color: #137EC4;
}
```

```html
<li>
    <span>x<span>
    <a>
    <span>Name one</span>
    <span class="num" >0.8</span>
    <span class="qty" >2</span>
    </a>
</li>
<li>
    <span>x<span>
    <a>
    <span>Name long</span>
    <span class="num" >9.99</span>
    <span class="qty" >2</span>
    </a>
</li>
      <li>
    <span>x<span>
    <a>
    <span>Name three name</span>
    <span class="num" >104.5</span>
    <span class="qty" >3</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

And my question is how can I put all li element with equal width? something like a table with rows. As you will see in my code, some numbers are no vertical aligned with its followed element. In brief, all number could look as a row, same size.

Comment: Did wo solve your problem? If yes, it would be nice to choose a correct answer!

Comment: Ok, Done ......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to achieve like table with rows and align the span vertically is easy you can try

**HTML**

```
<li>
    <span> Number 1 </span>
    <span class='qty'> 2.5 </span>
    <span class='num'> 1 </span>
</li>
<li>
    <span> Number 2 </span>
    <span class='qty'> 5.0 </span>
    <span class='num'> 2 </span>
</li>
```

**CSS**

```
li {
    width: 250px;
    height: 35px;
}

span.qty, span.num {
    float:right; 
    padding: 2px 1px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #0088cc;
    color: white;
    margin: 0 1px;
}
```

Check fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4m4wqyog/ 
Hope it helps :)